# How to monetize a cross-platform app in the correct way?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform, ads

I'm making an app using the ionic framework and i'm planning to develop for Android, Ios and Web. All three of the platforms do the same things in my app and the user can log in wherever he likes. The app will be free but with ads. No planning to add a paid app to remove the ads. 
 
I have no experience on this so I prefer asking.


How can I monetize all the three platforms?

Is there a plugin for cordova?

What is the best solution and the proper way to do this?

Is there a unique solution for all of the platforms?

 
Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 1):

I have not monetized a hybrid app yet, but I've worked with cordova and ionic for a while. Try this plugin that I found with a search. It should work for both IOS and Android (I don't think you would need a cordova plugin for web):

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

Google Admob/Adsense should allow you to have ads on all three platforms, so I guess that would be the way to go. You can familiarize yourself with it here:

https://developers.google.com/ads/

Comment: adMob doesn't let me monetize the web app, in that case i need to separate the ios and android app from the web version and use something else for the web browser

Comment: True. You can use the plugin above with Admob for the Android and Ios App. Then for mobile web/web app you would have to use Google Adsense. Those would be two different implementations

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AdMost](https://admost.github.io/). It optimizes the ad networks to maximize the revenue of applications. You can find Cordova documentation here:

https://admost.github.io/amrcordova/